# How to extract or get the image bounded by Detectron

Tags: image-segmentation, image-recognition, faster-rcnn, detectron, labelimg

I am working on creating bounding boxes upon images with my own created training dataset with the help of **Detection**, while I'm now stuck at the part of extracting the bounded image. **I just want the image of the part inside the bounding box.**
[The input image to predicted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv9nb.png)

[The predicted image with the bounding box outlines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48rFc.png)

Please help me with this query.[The resultant image should be like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUUu3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detection Function in Tensorflow

```
 # Detection Function
 detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

 bscores = detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy()
 bclasses = detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(np.int32)
 bboxes = detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy()

 det_boxes, class_labels = ExtractBBoxes(bboxes, bclasses, bscores, im_width, im_height, image_name=image_file)
```

Method to extract and crop bounding box

```
def ExtractBBoxes(bboxes, bclasses, bscores, im_width, im_height, image_name):
 bbox = []
 class_labels = []
 for idx in range(len(bboxes)):
    if bscores[idx] >= Threshold:
      #Region of Interest
      y_min = int(bboxes[idx][0] * im_height)
      x_min = int(bboxes[idx][1] * im_width)
      y_max = int(bboxes[idx][2] * im_height)
      x_max = int(bboxes[idx][3] * im_width)
      class_label = category_index[int(bclasses[idx])]['name']
      class_labels.append(class_label)
      bbox.append([x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, class_label, float(bscores[idx])])

      #Crop Image
      cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, y_min, x_min, y_max - y_min, x_max - x_min).numpy().astype(np.int32)
      output_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(cropped_image) #For Jpeg
      score = bscores[idx] * 100
      # Create a constant as filename
      file_name = tf.constant(youfilename)
      file = tf.io.write_file(file_name, output_image)
```